# how to generate this plot in html

Tags: html, css

I want to generate a figure like that given below. This fig mainly shows certain range locations along the length of a region .

The length of region is given in file1.txt as:

```
NP_123456.4: 110 
...
```

In one file, centain range for that region (file2.txt) is given as:

```
NP_123456.4: 30-45, 65-80
...
.
```

In another file (file3.txt), another region:

```
NP_123456.4: 35, 47-50, 58-59
....
..
```

Next file (file4.txt):

```
NP_123456.4: 38, 52, 69-88
..
```

As you see, each file has multiple ids (I omits them by ..) and for each id there will be a plot tike this. So there will be multiple plots in the output browsr.

I previously used gviz in R to plot them, but now, I need to do it in html. I never used this before and I appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks
[image: plot]

Comment: There's no easy way to do this in HTML, I would look into a library that makes something close to what you want.

Comment: That's something achievable with `HTML` and `CSS` but you need to tell how you are generating the resulting `html` after reading the files?

Comment: pardon me for my ignorance, but can't I generate a .html output file that contain all the plots for each id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a suitable programming language that generates the HTML for you**

You can generate an `html` output similar to the following approach:

```css
.canvas {
  margin: 50px;
}
.region {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:  50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
}
.region::before, .region::after {
  color: #00000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.2em;
 }
.region::before {
  content: "1";
  left: -20px;
}
.region::after {
  content: "110";
  left: 420px;
 }

.v-1, .v-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:  60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.v-1 {
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.v-2 {
  margin-left: 260px;
}


.v-1 > div, .v-2 > div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -20px;
  widht: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: .9em;
 }
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div class="region">
    <div class="v-1"><div>30-45</div></div>
    <div class="v-2"><div>65-80</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using Javascript for read the file and draw the graph**

Otherwise, if javascript is an option for you, you can create a simple html file with the following code for reading the file content:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
       var contents = e.target.result;
          alert(contents);  
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

The `contents` variable will hold the text content of the picked file. You can extract the ranges or single values after the `:` using regular expressions with javascript. 
You can then use these values and take advantage of the new drawing features of html5 to produce the graph accordingly.

For regular expressions with javascript, there are a lot of guides as a result of a google search. For reading about the new `canvas` html5 element and how to draw with javascript I've found this canvas tutorial -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial   - a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but please teach me how do you read the positions from file 1?

Comment: @J.Carter, that depends on what programming language/platform you are required to employ, and also where the input files are stored.

Comment: actually I intend to run it in from the current directory where these four input files are located, and I can use a python or R, but I can't relate how that script push data here.. but thank you very much for your help

Comment: Could javascript be an option for you? You can read the file through the browser and plot the resulting graph according to the parsed values.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some hint to start. If you have some difficulties with regular-expressions or with drawing with javascript, I'll help you.